# Laravel DOMPDF Direction issues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, pdf-generation, dompdf

I am trying to create a PDF that has `right to left` text blocks. I am using [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf). Im my template I have

```
body {
    font-family: Alef;
    direction:rtl;
    text-align:right;
}
```

I have also tried to add `unicode-bidi :embed;` and `unicode-bidi :bidi-override;`, the output however is not `rtl` but is still `ltr`.

My code is very straight forward:

```
    $fontsLocation = Storage::disk('local')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix()."fonts/";
    $pdf = PDF::setOptions(['fontDir'=>$fontsLocation,'defaultFont'=>'Alef-Regular']);
    $pdf->loadView('pdf/quota', $data);
    return $pdf->download($data["client"]."-".$data["id"].'.pdf');
```

Any advice will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work. In the end I simply switched to [mPDF](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf).